# Multiple countdowns on the same page JS

Tags: javascript, html

I know nothing about JS so please cut me some slack.
I am using a countdown from the W3schools website.
The problem is that even though I give the two countdowns separate IDs, it seems that they are running the same countdown, rather than being separate. Both seem to run sec-cd.

How can allow these two countdowns to work separately?

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
  <h1><u><b>Countdown 1</b></u></h1>
  <h1 id="main-cd"></h1>
  <div class="secondary">
    <h1><u><b>Countdown 2</b></u></h1>
    <h1 id="sec-cd"></h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var countDownDate = new Date("August 29, 2017 19:00:00 GMT").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("main-cd").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    var ongoing = document.getElementById("main-cd").innerHTML = "Fin";
  }

}, 1000);

var countDownDate = new Date("August 28, 2017 19:00:00 GMT").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("sec-cd").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    var ongoing = document.getElementById("sec-cd").innerHTML = "Fin";
  }

}, 1000);
```

**JSFiddle Link:** https://jsfiddle.net/az0upkxu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `countDownDate` variable twice. Just re-declare it has `countDownDateTwo` and also change `distance` to equal `countDownDateTwo - now` and it works.

Be careful with variable names, this is why scope is key.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are overriding same variable. Kindly use another variable.

```
var countDownDate = new Date("August 29, 2017 19:00:00 GMT").getTime();

var countDownDate_2 = new Date("August 28, 2017 19:00:00 GMT").getTime();// renmaed variable
```

also use these different variable names inside the code using these parameters.

**Below code will work.**

```
var countDownDate = new Date("August 29, 2017 19:00:00 GMT").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("main-cd").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        var ongoing =document.getElementById("main-cd").innerHTML = "Event Ongoing";
    }

}, 1000);
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate_2 = new Date("August 28, 2017 19:00:00 GMT").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate_2 - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("sec-cd").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        var ongoing =document.getElementById("sec-cd").innerHTML = "Season has eneded!";
    }

}, 1000);
```